# How to use Mocha testrunner instead of built-in

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm creating e2e test using WebdriverIO.
As I understand test-runner calling sequence is smth like 
`NPM (package.json) -> WDIO (wdio.conf.js) -> Mocha (via "wdio-mocha-framework")`

As far as i know, Wdio is designed for using built-in test-runner. But is there way for call wdio from mocha? This is needed for debug in IDE and run test separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '[standalone](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/modes.html#Standalone-Mode)' mode to require the test runner via Mocha.

There are a bunch of examples of standalone mode [on their github page](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/examples/standalone).