# Run WebdriverIO tests via Mocha in WebStorm

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm, webdriver-io

I want to run WebdriverIO + Mocha tests from the WebStorm gutter (the green triangle icons on the left side, by the line numbers).

[image]

But when I press run triangle - error occurred:

```
/Users/ilyubin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/node /Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --ui bdd --reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js /Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/test/specs/catalog/not.found.page.spec.js --grep "^Тесты страницы ошибок Поиск несуществующего запроса$"
/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/test/specs/catalog/not.found.page.spec.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {expect} from 'chai';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at /Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:324:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:321:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:763:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:196:16)
    at exports.runMocha (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:291:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:292:3)
    at Object.runCommand (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:238:44)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1072:28)
    at Object.parse (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:62:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ilyubin/git/ozon.ru/packages/ozon.ru-ui-tests/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

**How to run WebdriverIO tests from WebStorm?**

My versions:

```
WebStorm 2018.3.3
Build #WS-183.5153.33, built on January 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.2

➜ ~ node -v
v10.15.0

➜ ~ mocha --version
5.2.0
```

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.4.9",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.4.13",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.4.13",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.4.13",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.4.3",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.4.13",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: It looks like there's some sort of transpiling, or ES6 support issue on one end, due to the stack-trace syntax error on the `import` statements. I have no knowledge of WebStorm, but maybe look into how you debug ES6 projects on it, maybe there's some plugin you're missing. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You can't run wdio specs using mocha test runner, so **Mocha** run configuration can't be used here. You need using **Node.js** run configuration instead:

[image]

Also, as you are using ES6 syntax in your tests, you have to configure wdio to use babel. See https://webdriver.io/docs/babel.html for instructions:

- `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/register`
- in the project root folder, create a file `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      targets: {
        node: 8
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

- in your wdio.conf.js, set up mocha as follows;

```
mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000,
        compilers: ['js:@babel/register']
    },
```

Comment: Is it possible to link that nodejs run config to the run/debug buttons in the IDE in the test files?  Like can you set the default template for the temporary run configs that are automatically generated? otherwise I have to keep editing the "specs" of the wdio config manually for the test I am working on.

Comment: do you miss the run buttons in the gutter? no, this can't be done, running individual tests from gutter is only possible when using known test runners with dedicated run configurations

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. Yes I find the buttons very useful when quickly wanting to run a specific test while writing tests, without adding loads of .skip or .only or editing the "specs" etc (then forgetting it's been filtered!).

Comment: It's a shame that webdriverio runs mocha (or others) internally rather than allow itself to be run BY mocha like most test frameworks do. There's probably a way to invert it but I haven't figure it out yet. Vlad describes it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578696/how-to-use-mocha-testrunner-instead-of-built-in but the only suggestion about standalone didn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can run tests in this way with a plugin from the marketplace.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16147-webdriverio

Source code is here: https://github.com/winkingzhang/idea-run-wdio

I have just used installed this plugin, and now the run/debug buttons next to `describe` or `it`, or the shortcut keys, or via the project/file panel, generates the temporary templated run/debug config as expected.

The plugin author has made a new run/debug config dialogue with choices for the wdio package, runner framework, test file, env etc. which is pre-populated when used as above. So you could make your own permanent configs too as usual.

It worked out of the box, it seems to auto-detect all the configuration required.