# Webdriverio debug BDD tests using WebStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, mocha.js, babeljs, webdriver-io

Is there any way to debug Webdriverio tests using nodeJS and WebStorm? 
I've found some conclusion here and this is actually my problem: [Run WebdriverIO tests via Mocha in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610932/run-webdriverio-tests-via-mocha-in-webstorm)
But this solution doesn't fit to my problem now;
I've set up Babel to compile my BDD tests 
I've set tests.config.js

```
module.exports = {     maxInstances: 1,
capabilities: [{ browserName: 'chrome' }],
execArgv: ['--inspect'] : [],
specs: ['**/some/spec.js']
mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        compilers: ['js:@babel/register'],
        timeout: 150000
} }
```

and babel.conf.js

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
        targets: {
            node: 12
        }
    }]
]
```

}

then I've created nodeJS configuration like it said here at answer: [Run WebdriverIO tests via Mocha in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610932/run-webdriverio-tests-via-mocha-in-webstorm)
Set breakpoint at test

```
describe("test", function(){ 
it ("this is a BDD test", 
function(){
breakpoint here>> do_some_action();
})
})
```

But when I try to launch my tests in debug mode nothing happens and I see "connnected to localhost:port" message. and I can't go to breakpoint; there are no errors;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was problem with a wdio.conf.js file. If you don't set specs file >> there aren't no errors. But launching is incorrect. I've set config like this:

```
module.exports =
{
capabilities: [{
maxInstances: 6,
browserName: 'chrome',
baseUrl: "some-url/",
browserVersion: '67.0'}]
specs: [
'./this/is/spec.js']
mochaOpts: {
ui: 'bdd',
require: ['@babel/register'],
timeout: 150000
},
```

And debug works after this. It's not too har as I though :) If there are some questions - > I'm glad o answer

Comment: Are you referring to this part? specs: [
'./this/is/spec.js']